# Grab last part of the url inside rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have an url like this `http://example.com/en/username/Pimpampum`

And I have one rule to map it into a search page, but I want to grab that Pimpampum inside the rule. So that I can call the search for that name

```
add_rewrite_tag("%u%", '(.*)');

add_rewrite_rule(
  'username/(.+?)$',
  "index.php?pagename=search-result&u=".$matches[1],
  "top"
);
```

But I can't see how to grab the last part of the url.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doesn't it work `get_query_var('u')` to grab the variable ?

Also you need to use - `"index.php?pagename=search-result&u=". '$matches[1]'` , single quote surrounding `$matches[1]`.